# Clustering after minimum spanning tree cut

Tags: python, graph, union, intersection

What would be the optimal way of clustering nodes after cutting a MST with a maximum edge-length? My output from MST edge-length cut is a 2xN array where each element is an integer. The integers are the node identifiers that describe the edges. An example of the output would is given below:

```
>>> print array[0:3]
[[  0   1]
 [  0   2]
 [  2  17]]
```

I'm typically dealing with 100 to 20,000 nodes. My MST code is sufficiently fast, but it's being bogged down by the clustering/grouping algorithm. It's a loop-heavy set of functions and that's what is slowing it down. Check out the following code. Any ideas on how to speed it up? I'm aware that this is a brute force method, so a cleaner method would be best. Thanks in advance for your help!

Cheers,

Eli

```
def _super_intersection(edges):
    group = set(edges[0])
    index = np.array([0])
    k = 0
    while k < 100:
        k += 1
        i = 0
        for edge in edges[1:]:
             i += 1
             edge = set(edge)
             if group & edge:
                 group = group | edge
                 index = np.append(index, i)

index = np.unique(np.array(index))
return group, index


def cluster(self, gmin = 5):
    # A 2xN array of node IDs
    edges = self.edges
    group_nodes = {}
    for no, edge in enumerate(edges):
        try:
            group, indice = _super_intersection(edges)
            id_no = no                
            edges = np.delete(edges,indice,0)
            if len(group) >= gmin:
                group_nodes[id_no] = list(group)
        except:
            self.group_nodes = group_nodes
```

Comment: Your code seems to be malformed (the last two lines of _super_intersection are misindented).

Comment: I have to say I don't understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: My code is attempting to group nodes that are still connected by unbroken MST edges. If you were to plot the MST you could see what is a group visually, but now I'm trying to do that algorithmically. The code basically cycles through a 2D array. Each row is an 'edge' described by node numbers. The code then cycles through each row and creates larger sets between rows when an intersection is met. Once that's done, it will union the elements of the two rows into a set. Take that set and continue on through the rest of the array.

Comment: Thanks for catching the indentation issue as well. I was copying/pasting from my code, so that was lost somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. Go to the NetworkX google group link to see the solution.

http://groups.google.com/group/networkx-discuss/browse_thread/thread/4ac4250d460a1b75

Cheers,

Eli

Comment: That message explains the problem clearly (and with nice pictures), thanks!